# Convert Decimal to String on Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

example Code

```
Declare
    @table1  VARCHAR(MAX)

Set @table1 = 'Select * from @tempTbl'


Declare
    @List   VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Pivot  VARCHAR(MAX)

Select @List = ISNULL(@List + ',', '') + TrxCd From TransacMaster Where Module = 'CB' 

Set @Pivot = '
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DebtorCd ASC) As RowIndex, *
FROM (
    Select Distinct
        c.UserId, 
        d.Name, 
        b.TrxCd 
        SUM(b.Amount) As Amount
    From tbl_InvH a
    Inner Join tbl_InvD b on a.subCd = b.subCd and a.InvNo = b.InvNo 
    Left Join tbl_User c On a.UserId = c.UserId
    Left Join tbl_Personnel d on c.PersonnelId = d.PersonnelId
    Group By c.UserId, d.Name, b.TrxCd
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR TrxCd IN (' + @List + ')
)AS pvt'


Declare @Result nVarchar(MAX)

Set @Result = @table1 + ' 
Union All 
' + @Pivot

Exec sp_executesql @Result
```

I want to Convert Field Amount from decimal to String, because after this I want to UNION with another tables, but field amount and field from another table is different type.

I have tried CAST(SUM(Amount) as Varchar) But Error :

'CAST' is not a recognized aggregate function.

I can't Convert on Main Select because Field of TrxCd is Dynamic

Result Of Pivot

```
RowIndex  |  UserId   |   Name        |   IT01   |   IT02   |   IT03   |  IT04
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         |   John    |   John Ivy    |   2,000  |   2,000  |   1,000  |  5,000
2         |   Merry   |   Merry Ish   |   1,000  |   1,000  |   1,000  |  6,000
```

other Table

```
RowIndex  |  UserId   |   Name        |   Transac1   |   Transac2   |   Transac3   |  Transac4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         |   John    |   John Ivy    |   Trx Bank A |   Trx Bank B |   Trx Bank C |  Trx Bank D
```

What should I do to Convert Field Amount from Pivot.

Comment: Add the query with `UNION`

Comment: @Prdp UNION Query has been added

Comment: you do not really need a SUM() in the pivot, as the data is already summed in the source table. So, you can simply get away with a different aggregate function, such as MAX(), like this: `PIVOT ( MAX(CAST (Amount AS VARCHAR(20)))    FOR TrxCd IN (' + @List + '))AS pvt`

Comment: @cha I have tried like this but not work and have error in MAX(CAST(Amount as varchar))...

Answer (score 0):

Because of the dynamic nature, you could take the same `@List` expression `Select @List = ISNULL(@List + ',', '') + TrxCd From TransacMaster Where Module = 'CB'` and create a second for the dynamic casting in the main select;

```
Select @List2 = ISNULL(@List2 + ',', '') + 'cast(' + TrxCd + 'as varchar)' From TransacMaster Where Module = 'CB'
```

Then use this and additional columns required to replace the asterix in the main select;

```
'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DebtorCd ASC) As RowIndex, UserId, Name,' + @List2 +'....'
```